# Tracking changes in admin-page so user gets warning when leaving the page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field, wp-admin

An admin page with metaboxes and custom fields works fine, but when the user forgets to click "update" there is no warning "***Leave Site?*** Changes you made may not be saved.". This warning only works on changes of title and main content but not on the custom fields.

Does WordPress provide in a standard way to track changes on input fields and trigger the warning on page-leave?